# Does All() function return all documents in MongoDb before applying Where Condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am trying to learn MongoDb by using it in my .NEt MVC project. I tried to find a good tutorial to create enterprise level of using MongoDb library and I think I have done a good job. But I have a question that has been buging me.

I have the Get() function that returns a list of objects by a search criteria. You can see that there is All<>() function is used inside Get(). Does that All<>() get all documents from DB and applies the Where Condition? Or, does it get only documents that satisfies the Where Condition?

I couldnt set the profiler up to find my question's answer. That s why I am asking here. Please, no downvotes

```
    public IList<Article> Get(string UrlText)
    {
        return DbContext.Current.All<Article>().Where(d => d.UrlText.ToLower().Contains(UrlText.ToLower())).OrderBy(d => d.Id).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't look on MongoDb, DbContext is actually sign for an entity framework :)   Or it is a custom wrapper for a MongoDb Collection. I don't know any All() function in MongoDb driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB when called from .net enviroment is transfomed into a command, and from that command, query is created. (I cannot find source, so this might not be true anymore, but principle will be the same).

Then, when query is executed cursor, pointing to first document is returned to .net enviroment and method `All<>()` is generating a list form that cursor you got. Cursor has only items you requested, so after where condition is met.

*I assumed that we are using the same mongo wrapper :)*

This principle also applies to Limit, Skip, other queries like: Equal, GreaterThen, LeaserThen and all logical methods like And, Or...

**EDIT:**

All methods executed on mongoDB are narrowed down to something like this [mongo-csharp-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/a417730fc4225cb934728c2abeb056ad53901952/src/MongoDB.Driver.Legacy/MongoCollection.cs):

```
    private MongoCursor FindAs(Type documentType, IMongoQuery query, IBsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return MongoCursor.Create(documentType, this, query, _settings.ReadConcern, _settings.ReadPreference, serializer);
    }
```

Comment: I am using Norm.dll. So, All() doesnt return all documents, it returns only what I want, right?

Comment: If i remember right NoRM is not in development any more and wise move would be to shift twards newer, supported version https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver .

Yes, it filters everything that doesn't met condition out of All query.